# How to make an adjective from "весы"?

Tags: выбор-слова, прилагательные

- часы (a clock) - часовой (e.g "часовой магазин" - clock shop)
- час (an hour) - also часовой (e.g. "часовой пояс" - time zone)
- вес (weight) - весовой (e.g. "весовая категория" - weight class)
- весы (scales) - ?

Is it also "весовой"? It sound a bit strange. But the phrase "`весовое оборудование` - weighting equipment" googles...

`LANG=ru`:

Как образовать прилагательное от "весы"? "весовой", как с часами и часом? Не звучит (но гуглится)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, *весово́й*. Никакого другого прилагательного вы не образуете, за исключением случая, когда  *весы* — это кто-то одушевленный, например, человек соответствующего знака зодиака. Тогда, вероятно, возможно образование притяжательного *весо́вий*.

В чем, собственно, проблема? Что вы хотите выразить при помощи «прилагательного от слова „весы“», что оно у вас «не звучит»?

P. S. Если вам нужны цитаты из словарей, то держите, (выделение везде мое):

> весовой
>   *прил.*
>   1) Соотносящийся по знач. с сущ.: вес (1), связанный с ним.
>   2) Свойственный весу (1), характерный для него.
>   3) *разг.* Продаваемый и покупаемый на вес; развесной.
>   4) Соотносящийся по знач. с сущ.: **весы**, связанный с ним.

— словарь Ефремовой

> весовой
>   1. *см.* вес и **весы**.
>   2. Отпускаемый, продаваемый на вес, не поштучно. В. товар. В. хлеб.

— словарь Ожегова—Шведовой

> весовой
>   1. см. Вес.
>   2. см. **Весы**.

— «Большой толковый словарь» Кузнецова

> весовой
>   1. прил. к **весы**. Весовая гиря, стрелка.
>   2. Продаваемый на вес, а не поштучно (*спец.*). Весовой товар. Весовой хлеб.

— словарь Ушакова и вовсе удивляет отсутствием ссылки на *вес*, только на *весы*

Comment: There's the related adjective взвешенный (weighted). It seems to be more often used in technical contexts. Is that accurate?